# How do I do an Excel Web JSON query per row of a data in a table

Tags: excel, vba, database, powerquery

I am looking for a way to verify Sales Tax rates for transactions that are listed in a table in Excel. My Excel table has an "Address" column, and I would like to query the California sales tax API (https://services.maps.cdtfa.ca.gov/) to get back rate, jurisdiction, and other pieces of information that is provided by the JSON provided by the API. What I am looking for is a way to take that table of addresses and for each row either append to the table the information from the JSON. The query would effectively need to be run on each row using information within the row to create the query. An Example of an End Result being:

[image: Example End Result]

The above Example would use (https://services.maps.cdtfa.ca.gov/api/taxrate/GetRateByAddress?Address=1313%20Disneyland%20Dr&City=Anaheim&Zip=92802) as the query for that specific row.

Edit: I think I figured out the first part my problem was I did not know how to use the data within a row of a table as a parameter in the query. I have been able to get the result I am looking for by creating a function and invoking it as a new column, then since it is a JSON that is returned, Expand that into rows.

Now the problem I am having is that sometimes the JSON returned is a different format based on if there is one or multiple rates that are part of the combined total rate. I am not sure how to do conditional Transforms and my `try... otherwise` is not helpful the way i have it because then it errors out when trying to transform a null JSON when there is no reply.

My newest Below is my current code.

```
(URLParam as text) =>
let
    Source = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(URLParam), 65001) otherwise MissingField.UseNull,
    rate = Source[taxRateInfo]{0},
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(rate),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Converted to Table"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"jurisdiction", type text}, {"rate", type number}, {"city", type text}, {"county", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: Why not just run an update query to build that url string from your fields

Comment: @dbmitch I am sorry but I am not 100% sure what you mean. If I am being honest, it may be that simple, but I am not sure how. my issue I thought, is that some of the data is coming from my table, and then the rest is coming from an individual query per row. Are you able to point me to an example of what you are suggesting? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @dbmitch also, to clarify. The only data I have initially in my database is the address. the other information comes from a different source and the query is based on the value in an individual row, not like an SQL query where I can `UPDATE * WHERE....`

Comment: Do you just want a popup for the tax rate? Or are you looking for a new column that holds that rate? This is pretty simple to code in a function that parses the data for each record. Is it one-time - so you just update the table once? Or is it ad-hoc - with a button press one record gets updated?

Comment: @dbmitch I am hoping to have the right 5 columns from the image above to be added to an existing table. Technically it only needs to be updated once, but a function sounds like it is probably what I am looking for but not sure how to set-up the query in VBA, and would you recommend 5 separate queries for each row, or a function that "Spills" into adjacent cells? THANKS!

Comment: I think you need to update your question with more details. It's hard to read thru all your information and figure out what you have and what you want. If all you have is address you can get tax rate using your url to get and parse the JSON. Whey would you think 5 queries for each row are needed?

Comment: @dbmitch I have updated the question. Thank you for your help! I feel like my problem is I have knowledge of what needs to be done but not exactly how to do it, or the right terminology to ask for or search for the assistance I need. It is like knowing how an engine works, but having to build one and needing help with how to install some parts but not knowing what those parts are called... haha  Thanks for your patience with me!

Comment: Do you know how to insert code into a spreadsheet (turn it into an xlsm file - macro-enabled)?
You need a function that retrieves the data from internet url, and parses it from the JSON - then you can run whenever you want the table updated.

Comment: @dbmitch I know how to use VBA for most Excel Functions, but do not know how to query, retrieve the JSON, and manipulate it outside of using power query.

Comment: Looks like you made some progress. In Excel I would likely use a filter on rows that have empty tax rate and filled address columns. Process the results one row at a time in a loop.  You must have added an external JSON library for your query?

Comment: @dbmitch no, I was just using Power Query. Similar to what Ron Rosenfield posted, I just could not figure out the way to split out the different rates, and Filter out rows with errors. I figured out how to filter the error rows though too as I need to put it in the right spot within the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a table with two addresses

- The first returns a single tax rate
- The second returns two

[image]

We write a custom function which transforms the address into an api call, and then returns a `List` of the `Records` of the tax rate info.

*I named it `fnCaTax`*

```
(adr as text)=>

let 
    baseURL = "https://services.maps.cdtfa.ca.gov/api/taxrate/GetRateByAddress?",
    
    x = List.Transform(Text.Split(adr,","),each Text.Trim(_)),
    address = Text.Replace(x{0}," ","+"),
    city = Text.Replace(x{1}," ","+"),
    stateZip = Text.Split(x{2}," "),
    state = stateZip{0},
    zip = stateZip{1},

    apiCall=baseURL &
                "&Address=" & address &
                "&City=" & city &
                "&Zip=" & zip,

    json = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiCall)),
    taxRateInfo = json[taxRateInfo]    
    
in taxRateInfo
```

We then expand the `List` into new rows, and the `Records` in the `List` into new columns

```
...
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "fnCaTax", each fnCaTax([Column1])),
    #"Expanded fnCaTax" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function", "fnCaTax"),
    #"Expanded fnCaTax1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded fnCaTax", "fnCaTax", 
        {"rate", "jurisdiction", "city", "county", "tac"}, {"rate", "jurisdiction", "city", "county", "tac"})
in
    #"Expanded fnCaTax1"
```

To get:

[image]

***I did no testing for bad addresses or missing components of the address. You should add that if that is a possibility***

Comment: This is nearly exactly what I am looking for! I have one last question... do you have a suggestion if the address does not have that comma after the first portion of the address... I am working with my IT team to maybe get that added, but it is a limiting factor of the data I am receiving. Either Way, I will mark this as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Michael I suggest either creating a`List` of cities to check against; or possibly just supplying the zip code, if that is accepted by the API.

Comment: Ok, thanks Ron. Unfortunately, California requires street address, city, and zip to determine rate. but I am going to work with my IT team to have the delimiter added. Thank you for your help!